# jQuery ui autocomplete weird behavior

Tags: jquery, regex, jquery-ui, jquery-ui-autocomplete

I have started using jQuery-ui-autocomplete recently. However I am facing a strange and weired behavior. I am trying to use autocomplete for multi valued remote data (data from my data service). My code to extract the last term after the comma does not work. My code is as:

```
function split(val) {
    return val.split(/,\s*/);
}

function extractLast(term) {
    return split(term).pop();
}
```

Code for autocomplete is

```
$('#txtBox')
    .bind("keydown", function (event) {
        if (event.keyCode === $.ui.keyCode.TAB && $(this).data("autocomplete").menu.active) {
            event.preventDefault();
        }
    })    
    .autocomplete({
        minLength: 3,
        selectFirst: true,
        source: function (request, response) {
            $.ajax('My/Data/Source.json', {
                global: false,
                success: function (data) {
                    response($.map(data.d.results, function (item) {
                        return {
                            label: item.Name,
                            id: item.id
                        }
                    }));
                }
            });
        },
        search: function () {
            // custom minLength
            var term = extractLast(this.value);
            if (term.length < 3) {
                return false;
            }
        },
        focus: function () {
            // prevent value inserted on focus
            return false;
        },
        select: function (event, ui) {
            var terms = split(this.value);
            // remove the current input
            terms.pop();
            // add the selected item
            terms.push(ui.item.value);
            // add placeholder to get the comma-and-space at the end
            //terms.push("");
            this.value = terms.join(", ");
            return false;
        }
    });
```

When I put a debugger in the function "search", the term is always more than 3. That means it is not correctly evaluating the regular expression. When I include the term

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
```

it works perfectly. But i cannot include this in my pages. However in firefox this works correctly without doctype declaration also. I tried this in IE8 and IE9 both with no success.

---

**UPDATE**
After digging a bit further, found that the main issue lies with how IE and other browsers tries to split the last term with regular expression. With IE, when the second time it tried to split the terms after , (comma). Eg http://jsfiddle.net/mE6th/ try to open this link in chrome and IE and see the difference.

Comment: So what is you current doctype or don't you have any right now?

Comment: No doctype as of now. Please see my updates in question. Issue seems to narrow down regular expression i think.

Comment: I came across this article :   http://blog.stevenlevithan.com/archives/cross-browser-split

Comment: Please explain why you can't use a `DOCTYPE`, since you already have a solution if you include it.

Comment: Also, could you add an example of your `JSON` data please?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want the last term in a comma separated string can't you just use this `.split(',').pop()`, for example:

```
'java,c++,php'.split(',').pop();
```

gives "php"

Comment: Ultimately that is the one I did and it worked. Still what i have seen is that regex gives different results with different browsers. So simply removed and regex used the above results.

Comment: Well, if this is the accepted answer, then autocomplete in question title is totally misleading :(

Comment: Yes, it looks like my answer was a more acceptable solution to a different part of the problem, namely finding the last term in a comma separated string. The fact that jQuery autocomplete is the trigger might actually be inconsequential. Feel free to edit the title of the question if you have a more descriptive title :)